How do I get enable Copilot when viewing MS Teams videos in MS 365?
Use Case:
I want to click a link and open the chat from that meeting (in Teams) so that I can then view the Recording, transcript, etc. in Teams where I can also use Copilot (MS AI) to ask questions about the recording.
What I've tried:
Copying and opening the link to the video in Streams and to the link open the video in Teams. Both open the video in Streams, which does not give an option to use Copilot to analyze the recording.

